Finding the flux of a vector field across the positive part of a one-sheet hyperboloid
Am trying to calculate the flux of a vector field $â\{xyz;  xyz; xy\}$ across part of
A surface $S: z = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 - 1}$ where $x ≥ 0, y ≥ 0, 0 ≤ z ≤ √15$
It is also stated that the normal to the surface forms an acute angle with the z-axis.
Using Gauss' formula, the flux is equal to the triple integral of the divergence of the field â across a closed surface V.
Am having a bit of trouble setting up the boundaries for the triple integral.
I have tried converting to cylindrical coordinates and then having
$1≤r≤4$
$0≤ z ≤ √15$
$0 ≤ φ ≤ π/2$
(since going by the boundaries it's in the first quadrant).
I then evaluated
$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_{1}^{4} \int_{\sqrt{r^2 - 1}}^{\sqrt{15}} z \cdot (r \sin\phi + r \cos\phi) r \, dz \, dr \, d\phi$
this gave me 657/5
I then found the flux across the top part of the surface i.e $z=\sqrt15$ which was
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_{1}^{4} r^3 \sin\phi \cos\phi \, dr \, d\phi$$ because z is just a flat surface and the normal is n{0,0,1} and the k component of a is xy, hence the integrand being the dot product of the two (n and vector field a).
this gave me an answer of $\frac{225}{8}$ and subtracting the second answer from the first gave me $\frac{4131}{40}$ but this is incorrect.
Maybe there's some kinda flaw in my logic
Where might the issue be?

What about the lower base? And the sides?
